# Conditions in which SP Content DB gets locked

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, backup, content-database

Apart from Content Database backup, what are the other conditions in which a SharePoint Content Database may get automatically locked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If we don’t schedule the crawls properly, they could interfere with each other and cause locks on our search databases.
2. If we have large lists or libraries then a user who enumerates it could cause us to retrieve more than 5000 items which would cause a lock on the content database
3. If the any database or it’s logs need to grow, then during that time the database would lock

   - Poor performance in SQL server could cause any database to lock
   - Memory contention
   - CPU starvation
   - Poor disk performance
   - MAXDOP not being set properly could cause locks on any database (Performance issue)
   - Overlapping process accessing a single database ie Backup, Crawl, Users, Antivirus, or any other 3rd party app.
   - Admins accessing database with T-SQL query that doesn’t use ‘No lock’
   - A single workflow could cause a lock on the database
   - Deep Site/List Hierarchy could cause a lock on the content  database
   - Certain web parts could cause locks on the content database if used in certain ways.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/christwe/archive/2013/05/16/sharepoint-tidbits-table-database-locks-what-causes-these-locks.aspx